# Delphi 2010 - Show form at memo seltext

Tags: delphi

Can anyone help me to display (or create) a form positioned (X, Y) in a memo  based on the last character typed by the user? Ie, I need a form is displayed whenever the user types in a memo the % character, yet need the form to be positioned immediately adjacent and below this character. I'm using this code:

```
procedure TForm1.memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
if key = #37 then
begin
  form2.Top:=Mouse.CursorPos.Y;
form2.left:=Mouse.CursorPos.X;
form2.Show;
end;
end;
```

But this code only show a form based on the cursor position . Is there a way to display and position the form to the right and below where the user entered the% character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the caret position, not the mouse postion ..

Try this instead

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  clientPos: TPoint;
begin
if key = #37 then

begin
    GetCaretPos(clientPos);
    clientPos:=Memo1.ClientToScreen(clientPos);
    with form2 do
    begin
      Top  := clientPos.Y + 4;
      Left := clientPos.X;
      Visible := true;
    end;
end

end;
```

Comment: Instead of `GetCaretPos()`, I would suggest using [`EM_POSFROMCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761631.aspx).